# Gradient applied to tr renders at each td separately. How to create horizontal-gradient on tr?

Tags: html, css, html-table

You can see the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/vadirn/5pgXS/1/ (only -webkit-gradient used).

Html:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Row one, column one</td>
    <td>Row one, column two</td>
    <td>Row one, column three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row two, column one</td>
    <td>Row two, column two</td>
    <td>Row two, column three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row three, column one</td>
    <td>Row three, column two</td>
    <td>Row three, column three</td>
  </tr>
</table>​
```

Scss:

```
$solid: 1px solid #444;
table {
    border: $solid;
}
td, th {
    border-right: $solid;
    border-bottom: $solid;
}
tr {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #fff 0%, #444 50%, #ffffff 100%);
}
```

​

Somehow background-image applied to tr:nth-child and tr doesn't work on tr, but on td instead.

Comment: FWIW, it looks like Google Chrome version 59 applies the gradient to the tr as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok just got what you were trying to say here, so give `background` to `table` instead of `tr` and use `background: #ffffff;` for your `odd/even tr`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5pgXS/4/)

CSS

```
$solid: 1px solid #444;
table {
    border: $solid;
    background: #1e5799;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #1e5799 0%, #7db9e8 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#1e5799), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #1e5799 0%,#7db9e8 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #1e5799 0%,#7db9e8 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #1e5799 0%,#7db9e8 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  #1e5799 0%,#7db9e8 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=1 );
}
td, th {
    border-right: $solid;
    border-bottom: $solid;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
   background: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: @SidharthMudgal done, you can take back your -1 and thanks for noticing

Comment: Great solution to the problem. My issue is a little more complex, as I wish to have different gradients on some of the rows. +1